# NUCLEO-F429ZI STM32 Cube IDE Initial Setup LED wont Blink

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, blink

I have been doing development with Arduino for about a year. I recently got a NUCLEO - F429ZI board and have tried without success to get a very basic LED blink programming working. I am using the STM32cube IDE and have followed all of the online tutorials but nothing seems to work to my frustration.

I have checked that all jumpers are connected and that the GPIO pins are properly formatted. My led is connected via a resistor to PA3. No matter what code I use in the while loop the led does not blink. See below:

```
 while (1)
{
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(BLINKLED_GPIO_Port, BLINKLED_Pin);
  HAL_Delay(1000);
/* USER CODE END WHILE */
 /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
}
```

[Microcontroller GPIO Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT5RT.png)

If anyone could point out where I am going wrong here it would be brilliant because I'm all out of ideas!!

Comment: I can set the on board LEDS high via the pinout and configuration page but I get no response if I try and Blink them in the while loop.

Comment: If the SysTick is not configured correctly sometimes `HAL_Delay()` can 'hang' - in which case your `while()` loop will not run properly.
Have you tried using the debugger in STM32CubeIde to verify that `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin()` is being hit once a second?